# How to deal with answers that are "Essentially a spam"

Tags: discussion, answers, spam

So I came across [an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1704524/1219498) while reviewing late answers that was essentially a spam and was focused on promoting the poster's own program and website. His own profile and his answer ("*our*" step-by-step guide) says that. However, at the same time the answer provides a solution to the question, too. So, what exactly should be done with the answer?

Note: Not-a-duplicate of [this Q](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13187/how-to-deal-with-spamanswer)

Comment: Flag it as spam. It probably even installs malware on your system. But even if it doesn't, it's clearly spam and should be deleted. The answer exists solely to promote their product. Would you trust installing software you've never heard of from a website in china?

Comment: I wouldn't.....

Comment: Flag it as spam. Six spam flags and it'll get deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think it's "essentially spam", you're in fact saying that it's spam.

In other words, if the whole point of the answer is to promote some off-site product/site/resource, and the answer doesn't seem salvageable if you remove those off-site references, there's no point in keeping it. Flag it as spam and let the system run its course.